# How can I add a material to a curve like a regular mesh?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, bezier-curves

How can I add a material to a Bezier curve like you would in a regular mesh,  in Cycles?

[image]

Comment: Do you mean to a part of a curve, or just to the whole object?

Comment: The whole object :) the circle was meant to show the 'geometry'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Adding a material to a curve is actually very simple :).
[image]

Adding the *Image Texture*, which is correctly UV mapped is much harder. If it is an object which won't be visible well in render (a background element for example) you may use this kind of node setup. The texture distortion wouldn't be much visible...
[image]

But the seams would.
[image]

You may try to blur them a little increasing the *Blend* factor in *Image Texture Node*.
[image]

If you don't want to have the seams visible, the only way is to use ***Convert to mesh from Curve*** option (<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>), then unwrap the mesh and use the *UV Coordinates* in *Texture Coordinate Node*. Next paint over the seams in *Texture Paint Mode*.
[image]

As @NoviceInDisguise said, you may always try to use *Procedural Texture* and use the *Generated Coordinates*.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible in standard workflow as far as UV maps go (Maybe some Python geek can figure something out). However, generated UV's work very well. That means any procedural material will work on them properly. You will need to convert to meshes and unwrap them to use image textures.

[image]

Or with a circular bevel on a curve:

[image]