# How apply texture to a curve

Tags: texturing, bezier-curves

I have a cable texture and a simple curve. I want to map the texture on the curve so that it looks like a cable.

[image]

[image]

Note : I dont want to convert the curve to mesh and the map with uv. Reason is i dont want to make more verts and the file size heavy.

Any suggestion. Thanks

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/22939/how-can-i-add-a-material-to-a-curve-like-a-regular-mesh

Comment: @brockmann the answer are to old and the version also to old. Will moonboots have given the answer. Thats what i was looking for.

Comment: Don't get the difference (functionality of the mapping node still the same in 2.9)... Same question too, moonboots can add the answer over there (that's how this site works).

Comment: @brockmann: if you are a bloody beginner (and i was a few month ago) the blender versions seem to look very different and you are sometimes totally lost although it is pretty much the same...

Comment: A beginner with 9K rep? Disagree on the mapping node looks different. Multiple reasons to close this as a dupe IMHO: it's even the **same question** and **shows no research effort** (basically nothing). Also, we can always **add new answers** to the other Q&A or **update the existing answers**. That's how this site works @Chris

Comment: @brockmann: i didn't check his reputation and where it comes from. Sometimes you gained the reputation from years ago. And it's human to forget things ;) And yes, we could update the answer. That's right...and maybe ...just a guess...someone else uses his account too ;)

Comment: it's not really the same question, he's specifically asking about an image texture on a curve, there must be the answer somewhere though as it is a basic

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you choose a value of *Scale* > 1.5 and Z *Rotation* > 90°, it will work better (still not perfect as it is not a repeatable texture and also it will squeeze on some parts because of the UV mode, but I don't think you can avoid that):

[image]

Comment: Thanks thats what i was looking. How it works for the curve can u plz let me know in detail.

Comment: what do you mean by "how it works for the curve"? I'm not sure there's any perfect way to texture with an image texture as you will always have some parts that will squeeze (unless I miss a way to do it correctly), but a thing that you can do to improve your texture is making it repeatable, it is not the case here. It all depends on your final goal actually, if you can hide the bad part it's ok

Answer (score 4):

Another possibility would be to use procedural textures like this:

[image]

Of course you should tweak it a bit more that it looks like you want it.

result:

[image]

Comment: Zackerly. Beat me to it :D